# semantic-ui accordion I dont want close if only 1 left open even you click

Tags: semantic-ui

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion();
```

I dont want close if only 1 left open even you click

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/definition

This is my current setup and you can see below my html structure

```
<div class="ui accordion">
  <div class="active title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
   title 1
  </div>
  <div class="active content">
    <p>para1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
   title 2
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>para1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
     title 3
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>para 3</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I just had to use this very feature - works:

here are my settings on .js:

$('.ui.accordion').accordion({'animateChildren': false, 'duration': 10, 'collapsible': false});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with the accordion right now and saw your question looking for an answer of my own..

I believe you want to leave the 'exclusive' behavior to true and set the 'collapsible' behavior to false.

The way I am reading it is that exclusive only allows one section open at a time (this is the default) and collapsible does not allow you to collapse a section if it is open already

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/settings

Hope this helps somewhat